# Form validation is not displaying results on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My form validation was not displaying errors on my `posts/create` route. I Googled the solution and found that

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
    Route::resource('/posts','PostsController'); 
});
```

can be changed to

```
Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => 'web'], function() {
    Route::resource('/posts','PostsController');
});
```

I did that and the problem is solved now. I want to ask if this is considered a good practice to change it like this?

Also if I am removing this line from my routes it is working:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
```

Can anyone tell me what is actually happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason can be that `web` middleware is applying two times in your case. Laravel by default adds web Middleware in `app/Providers/RoutesServiceProvider.php` and again you are adding it in your routes.php
Try it by removing `web` middleware from your routes.php.

Comment: yeah it is working after I remove them .Thanks for the answer .
I have a doubt ..If we look at kernel then "web=>" is located in "protected $middlewareGroups" and not in "$middleware" ..why ?

Comment: It is because web is a group composed of several other middleware so we have to use "protected $middlewareGroups" otherwise we have used "protected $middleware" for single middleware.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Laravel 5.3 documentation explains it in detail. 
Here is the link.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#middleware-groups

But to answer your question, this line:

> Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {

doesn't allow any request to access the routes inside only if they validate a condition which is inside the "web" middleware.

This is how laravel works. The doc gives more detail about each component in the framework.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ..
in my case when I grouped all the routes in 
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() { 
it was not displaying the errors on the page
then I looked at the kernel and found that "web" is actually in "protected middlewareGroup".
So I grouped it in 
Route::group(['middlewareGroup' => 'web'], function() {

Was this approach correct or should I leave it ungrouped ?